# Prolog predicate to generate integers above X on backtrack

Tags: prolog

> Write a predicate `above(L, N)` that will generate (on backtracking) each of the
>   integers larger than a given integer, `L`. For example, the goal `above(3, N)` should
>   generate as solutions `N = 4; N = 5; N = 6; ...`, and so on in order on backtracking.

As above.

A general strategy for "generating solutions on backtrack" would be great too.

Comment: @Flexo: Why are you voting to close this? It is a completely OK question.

Comment: @Bart: Why are you voting to close this? It is a completely OK question.

Comment: @false That's...well, false. This is nothing but a "give-me-teh-codez" question. It's blanket homework question without any apparent effort by the OP. So it's by no means an OK question.

Comment: @Bart: The question is a frequently recurring question even if the asker most probably retyped the question from an assignment.

Comment: @false That doesn't make it a good question by any means. We are not here to do the OP's homework.

Comment: @Bart: It is a frequently recurring question. I can only repeat this. Regardless of whether or not OP had this as homework.

Comment: @false Still a crap question. In fact, it's not a question at all. This is not a practical problem the OP faces. But this really is not the place to discuss this in depth. If you want to discuss this any further, take it to Meta. I'd happily answer you there.

Comment: @Bart: I can only express regret.

Answer (score 3):

```
   length(_,N), N > 3.

   length(_,I), N is I + 4.
```

These are not the most efficient versions, but they do not require an auxiliary definition.

```
   length([_,_,_,_|_],N).
```

Might be faster, but is a bit more obscure.

Comment: That is extremely inefficient and, for me, both of them are obscure.

Comment: This what I got from **measuring** `time((vx(N),N=10000000)).` in SWI with each of above versions defined as `vx(N) :- length(_,N), N>3.` etc: gusbro: 8.461s, v1: 12.723s, v2: 14.834s, v3: 9.908s.

Comment: And here, with another query: `time(v3(10000000)).` gusbro: 5.594s, 
v1: **0.213s**, v2: 13.314s, v3: **0.186s**.

Comment: I don't know what is v3, is it the last example ? OP wanted a predicate with 2 arguments, not a fixed one so i don't think that your last example is valid (e.g. first parameter to be 10000000)

Comment: @gusbro: In that case, only v1 and v2 are relevant - but they do not appear to be that inefficient... Your version could probably be faster by avoiding the repeated evaluation.

Comment: Right, they are not that inefficient as i presumed. And yes, my version would be probably faster by only evaluating once, but i thought it is clearer as it is now.

Answer (score 1):

You would need a procedure with two clauses.
The first one would be the base case which for the input number L unifies the output number N with L+1.
The second clause would be the recursive step, which just increments L and calls recusively above/2.

```
above(L, NL):-
  NL is L+1.
above(L, NL):-
  ML is L+1,
  above(ML, NL).
```

Comment: For the test case "above(3, N)", Prolog gives "N = 4 yes", with no option to backtrack.

Comment: You have to press the `;` key to get another result.

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. Perhaps the problem is a quirk of SICStus Prolog?

Comment: I don't have SICStus to try it, but am 100% sure the program is fine. You are trying the code from SICStus toplevel, right ?. In other prolog systems you can press enter instead of ; to receive new answers.

Comment: SICStus should use ";" to backtrack for more solutions.